# How to insert user input to Postgres Db with Go

Tags: postgresql, go

I am trying to insert a string to a Postgres database. And I couldn't find the correct syntax. Here is the code:

```
func insertdb() {
    fmt.Println("Write your text")
    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
    insertstmt := `insert into "todos"("do_info") values(**I need this**)`
    _, e := DB.Exec(insertstmt)
    checkError(e)
}
```

I want to insert the `input` variable to my Postgresql database. How should I write it after values in sql query?

```
values($1)
```

Error says need a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code complains beacause the query has a placeholder `$1` and it does not have a matching argument passed to the `Exec` function.

You have to pass the input to the `Exec` function so that it can replace the placeholder. i.e:

```golang
    fmt.Println("Write your text")
    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
    insertstmt := `insert into todos (do_info) values($1)`
    _, err = DB.Exec(insertstmt, input)
```